# Video html5 does not work in all browsers except google chrome

Tags: html, video

Video html5 does not work in all browsers except google chrome.

Firefox display: No video with supported format and MIME type found

Html in page:

```
 <video width="320" height="240" controls>
        <source src="http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.mp4" type="video/mp4">
 </video>
```

Comment: What MIME type are you serving the video file with?  Be aware that [Firefox only supports MP4 on recent Windows version](http://caniuse.com/mpeg4).

Answer (score -1):

According to W3 schools, only MP4 is not supported on Firefox. So if you are trying to display MP4, don't expect much from it. Also, Opera and Firefox offer build-in decoding for this feature.

Comment: Some notes: 1: https://hacks.mozilla.org/2012/03/video-mobile-and-the-open-web/ 2: http://caniuse.com/mpeg4  3: http://www.w3fools.com/

Comment: The fact that some people have "allergy" to some websites, this doesn't prevent us to present solutions to problems. We are talking about functionality and correctness.